# "The other chapters of this book" or "other chapters of this book"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

To refer to all chapters except of the current one: "the other chapters of this book" or "other chapters of this book" (without "the")?

Comment: "The other chapters of this book / in this book..."

Comment: @rkchl It would depend one what's meant.  If it's *all* the other chapters, then "the chapters" would make sense.  if it's only some of them, then "the" should be omitted.  Of course, that would change if there's more in the sentence that restricts it.  E.g., "Other chapters in this book also cited Smith." means "some of them did", whereas "The other chapters ... also cited Smith" means "all of them did."  But compare with "The other chapters ... that cited Smith ..." vs. "Other chapters that cited Smith ...".

Comment: He already said in his question that "To refer to **all** chapters except of the current one..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Others* means *some others* and *the others* means *all the others*. Likewise, *another* means *one of the others* and *the other* means *the only other*.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I reread your question and realize you want to refer to *all the other chapters*. You would almost always use *the* for this.

However, I don't want to delete this answer, as I think it has some useful information.

Using the definite article makes a definite reference. Without the definite article it does not make a definite reference.

definite reference:
1 I really like Chapter 2 of this book. But I dislike *the other chapters*.

There are only so many other chapters. By saying **the other chapters** you are referring to *a known set of chapters*. This can be all the other chapters or a previously referenced subset of them.

not a definite reference:
2 I really like Chapter 2 of this book. But I dislike **other chapters**.

By saying *other chapters* you are referring to an *indefinite amount or indefinite subset* of chapters. You are basically being vague about *which chapters* you mean.

Perhaps you don't even know exactly which "other chapters" you dislike (maybe they are chapters 2, 5, 11,and 17 but you can't remember their numbers). So you can just say "other chapters" to indicate this.

Thus you can also use *some* as a sort of plural indefinite article, in this context. You know there are *some* chapters that you dislike, but you do not want to or cannot *specify* which exact ones.

An indefinite reference comes across as vague because it is vague. It is not definite. *Other chapters*, *some other chapters* and *some chapters* are all indefinite references. They refer to chapters that have not been *specified*.

By contrast, *the other chapters* refers to a definite set of chapters, either all the other chapters, or some known or previously referenced subset, for example *the* chapters about noun phrases in a grammar book.